# Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 and Mac compatibility issues

Tags: communication, laser, rangefinder

I've got my hands on this laser range scanner but seem to have some problem receiving any output from it.

I can't find any guide on  how to set it up on the internet, so I was wondering if it is even possible to set it up for mac or shall i do it using Linux and ROS ?

Comment: How do you communicate the SCIP 2.0 commands?